# How to adjust a sound clip's volume in real time using DShow.h and strmiids.lib with C++

Tags: volume, audio, directx-9, directsound

I am trying to figure out how to set the volume in in real time that my sound clips play at in my C++ program, and do things like make the volume of the sound increase as 2 objects move closer to one another. Right now, I am using "DShow.h" as well as "strmiids.lib", and I am using the interface provided by the following data member pointers:

```
IGraphBuilder* m_graphBuilder;

IMediaControl* m_mediaControl;

IMediaEvent*   m_mediaEvent;

IMediaSeeking* m_mediaSeeking;
```

Using the interface provided by these, is there a way to alter the volume of the media stream playing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [IBasicAudio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd389532%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) interface.